# Twig IF ( .. OR .. ) Error

Tags: twig

here is a twig error again: (Don't know, why twig punish me..)

Snippet:

```
{% if (formDataValues.id OR formDataValues.ID) %}
....
{% endif %}
```

What i wanna do:
Check, if one of these values are given in my array.

My Error:

> Twig_Error_Syntax [ 0 ]: An opened parenthesis is not properly closed. Unexpected token "name" of value "OR" ("punctuation" expected with value ")") in "MY/PATH/TO/FILE" at line 1

May you have some creative ideas..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you try with a lowercase `or` and parentheses around the values?

```
{% if (formDataValues.id) or (formDataValues.ID) %}
....
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Wow.. Lowercase m( You saved my day! Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Tyralcori Glad to help! If this answers your question please mark it as such :)

Comment: Of course. But you can mark the answer after 15 min. after you created the question.. so i have to wait ;)